# jQuery function - set String parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a web page and I want to give a alert whenever I clicked a row of the generated table that is generated by the below code. In order to do that I am using setAlert(message) function.
My problem is that it only works when the parameter that is set to the function is a integer. it doesn't work when it is a String.
Help me solve this problem.

Thank you.

```
function getItemList(){
        $('#tableItem').empty();
        $.ajax({
                url: 'ItemServlet',  
                data:{version:2},
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#tableItem').append('<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="table1">\n\
                        <thead><tr><th class="table-text-align-centre" style="width:10%">Item Code</th>\n\
                                    <th class="table-text-align-centre" style="width:20%">Name</th>\n\
                                    <th class="table-text-align-centre" style="width:50%">Description</th>\n\
                                    <th class="table-text-align-centre" style="width:10%">Stock Count</th>\n\
                                    <th class="table-text-align-centre" style="width:10%">Active</th></tr></thead><tbody class="table-hover"></tbody></table>');
                    var length = data.length;
                    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        var post = data[i];
                        $('#table1').append('<tr onClick="setAlert('+post['itm_code']+')"><td>' + post['it_name'] + '</td>\n\
                        <td class="table-text-align-centre">' + post['itm_name'] + '</td>\n\
                        <td class="table-text-align-centre">' + post['itm_description'] + '</td> \n\
                        <td class="table-text-align-centre">' + post['itm_stockcount'] + '</td> \n\
                        <td class="table-text-align-centre">' + post['active'] + '</td> \n\
                        </tr>');
                    }
                }
            });
    }



    function setAlert(message) {
        var id = message+ "";
        alert(id);
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work? what exactly is happening ? is method getting called ? any error in console ?

Comment: now a days OP are like . can you correct this code without telling the error . thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you are passing your parameters into the `setAlert` function without defining the quotes. Now because you are using **"** to define your `onClick` and your using **'** to formulate you html, you need to use an apostrophe escaped **\'** to pass in the parameter.

So currently, if `post['itm_code']` is 1, it will generate the following html with valid javascript:

```
<tr onClick="setAlert(1)"><td>
```

However if `post['itm_code']` is a string "my string", it will render the following html with invalid javascript:

```
<tr onClick="setAlert(my string)"><td>
```

So the following line:

```
<tr onClick="setAlert('+post['itm_code']+')"><td>
```

should be changed to:

```
<tr onClick="setAlert(\''+post['itm_code']+'\')"><td>
```